# Converting RDD into a dataframe int vs Double

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Why is it possible to convert an rdd[int] into a dataframe using the implicit method

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

//Concatenate rows
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array(4,5,6)).toDF()
rdd1.show()

rdd1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int]
+---+
| _1|
+---+
|  4|
|  5|
|  6|
+---+
```

but rdd[Double] is throwing an error:

```
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Array(1.1,2.34,3.4)).toDF()
error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Spark 2.x**

In Spark 2.x `toDF` uses `SparkSession.implicits` and provides `rddToDatasetHolder` and `localSeqToDatasetHolder` for any type with `Encoder` so with

```
val spark: SparkSession = ???
import spark.implicits._
```

both:

```
Seq(1.1, 2.34, 3.4).toDF()
```

and

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(1.1, 2.34, 3.4)).toDF()
```

are valid.

**Spark 1.x**

It is not possible. Excluding `Product` types `SQLContext` provides implicit conversions only for `RDD[Int]` (`intRddToDataFrameHolder`), `RDD[Long]` (`longRddToDataFrameHolder`)  and `RDD[String]` (`stringRddToDataFrameHolder`). You can always `map` to `RDD[(Double,)]` first:

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(1.1, 2.34, 3.4)).map(Tuple1(_)).toDF()
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. Do you know whether it is due to the way Spark handles doubles or is it because the function was not included in the implicit method?

Comment: Nothing special about `Double`. It is simply not implemented.